# jquery - returning a page to its original layout

Tags: jquery, layout, refresh, toggle

I have a form that has some logic, you get a few more form option depending on what you click

```
$('input[value=buy]').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
           $('.form-field').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
           $('.form-field').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
```

The problem is toggling this leaves a big gap as .form-field is about 500px high. How can I toggle this and get this page to revert back?

I don't want to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `hide` and `show` method.

I guess your `hidden` class uses `visibility:hidden;` you should use `display:none;`.

More information can be found on the links below:

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/show/

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/